# Reading XML from URL using PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

Until today for some reason I was able to use the below code to read the XML from an external URL with no issues.

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'MY XML';
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

now I get a warning message instead that reads

*Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure*

i'm in a bit over my head here. I've tried using cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));
$xml = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

But for some reason this crashes the simplexml load and gives me this warning.
*Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found*

Any suggestions on what I'm missing here? The header on the XML file i'm trying to read is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ArrayOfCompetition xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Web.Controllers">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `0` or remove the line, because your curl code is include the headers in the write callback.

Read https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADER.html